# Can not Download File using HttpClient

Tags: java, download, httpclient

Below code is what I have tried so far:

```
try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://somewebsite.com");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                entity.consumeContent();            
            }
            System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
            List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://www.somewebsite.com/MemberSingIn");

            List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "USERNAME"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "PASSWORD"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rememberMe", "true"));

            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
            entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                entity.consumeContent();
            }

            System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
            cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            String mySessionId = null;
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    if(cookies.get(i).toString().contains("SessionId=")){
                        int index1 = cookies.get(i).toString().indexOf("SessionId");
                        String temp = cookies.get(i).toString().substring(index1);
                        int index2 = temp.toString().indexOf("]");
                        temp = cookies.get(i).toString().substring(index1+10,index1+index2);
                        mySessionId = temp;
                    }
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }      

            CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); 
            BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("Cookie",mySessionId);

            cookieStore.addCookie(cookie); 
            httpclient.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

            httpget = new HttpGet("http://somewebsite.URLTOGETFILE/eTable.txt");
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            entity = response.getEntity();
            System.out.println("HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
            System.out.println(response.toString());

            System.out.println("File get: " + response.getStatusLine());

            InputStream in = entity.getContent();


              File path = new File("/home/mrsevensevenseven/");
              path.mkdirs();
              File file = new File(path, "myfile.txt");
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              int len1 = 0;
              while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                      fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
              }

              fos.close();

            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It successfully, logs me in but I can not still download the file... Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.. I have tried a lot on stack overflow and googling around but couldn't get help with..

And this is the response...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head><title>
    IBD eTables - Investors.com
</title><meta property="og:title" content="IBD eTables" /><meta property="og:type" content="article" /><meta property="og:url" content="http://research.investors.com/etables/default.aspx" /><meta property="og:image" content="http://www1.ibdcd.com/images/IBDicon_309171.png" /><meta property="og:site_name" content="Investor's Business Daily" /><meta property="fb:app_id" content="154916351273272" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var divHeight;
    </script>
<link href="../App_Themes/eTables/eTablesStyles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/global.js?v=4"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/Silverlight.js?v=4"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/LaunchMSTool.js?v=4"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="/etables/default.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>


<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=RNfHbK6XxGlvk7UnQPQl5VWdSmPtL605im1i9ZMMuXgrvwYOrYkRhhjS5Tkc95LZKqMA01lmkm3Rvv6OCYTXQO0Wvej6DzniFUlixhkXWzmpvwOMQ0v-ompHlYoQzp1H0LzWltEL_D_EvsXg_ayZnY1oHnA1&amp;t=ffffffff8dc250fc" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Services/SiteAjaxService.asmx/js" type="text/javascript"></script>






<a id="hlRoadBlock" class="ex5trigger" rel="/Register/Roadblock.aspx?id=ETB&closepop=1" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>

    <a id="hlSignInRoadBlock" class="ex5trigger" rel="/Register/WeeklyEmails.aspx?id=etb" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>            

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isEntitled = ToBoolean("false");
        var isWeekly = ToBoolean("false");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/ExternalScripts/eTables.js"></script>


<div id="etbtop"></div>
<div id="etbmiddle">
    <div id="etbDummyImage" style="display:none;">
        <img id="staticeTableImage" src="http://www.investors.com/image/bgeTablesSm.png.cms" style="border-width:0px;" />
    </div>
    <div id="etbcontent" style="display:none;">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="etbbottom"></div> 
<div class="jqmWindow" id="ex5"></div>





<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var iLoginFlag = 0;var sAccess = "PVC";var sDGOProductsSite = "premium.investors.com";//]]>
</script>
</form>

    <!-- BEGIN: Site Tagging -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javaScript">if (typeof(s) != 'undefined'){s.server="IBDWEB21";s.events="";s.channel="Stock Research";s.pageName="";s.pageType="";s.hier1="Stock Research,eTables";s.products="";s.state="";s.zip="";s.purchaseID="";s.prop1="";s.prop2="";s.prop3="eTables";s.prop4="";s.prop5="";s.prop6="";s.prop7="";s.prop8="";s.prop9="";s.prop10="Tools";s.prop11="";s.prop12="Visitor";s.prop13="";s.prop14="";s.prop15="";s.prop16="eTables";s.prop17="";s.prop18="";s.prop19="";s.prop20="";s.prop21="";s.prop22="";s.prop23="";s.prop24="";s.prop32="";s.prop33="";s.prop34="";s.prop35="";s.prop36="";s.prop37="";s.prop38="";s.prop39="";s.prop40="";s.prop41="";s.prop42="";s.prop43="";s.prop44="";s.prop45="";s.prop46="";s.prop47="";s.prop48="";s.prop49="";s.eVar1="";s.eVar2="";s.eVar3="";s.eVar4="";s.eVar5="";s.eVar6="";s.eVar7="";s.eVar8="";s.eVar9="";s.eVar10="";s.eVar11="Visitor";s.eVar12="";s.eVar13="";s.eVar14="";s.eVar15="";s.eVar16="eTables";s.eVar17="";s.eVar18="";s.eVar19="";s.eVar20="";s.eVar21="";s.eVar22="";s.eVar23="";s.eVar24="";s.eVar25="";s.eVar26="";s.eVar27="";s.eVar28="";s.eVar29="";s.eVar30="";s.eVar31="";s.eVar32="";s.eVar33="";s.eVar34="";}</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // custom variables
    if (typeof(s) != 'undefined')
    {
        s.pageName = "eTables - IBD 50 Index - Standard Stock Data";
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javaScript">if (typeof(s) != 'undefined'){try{var s_code=s.t();if(s_code){document.write(s_code);}}catch(e){}}</script>
    <!-- END: Site Tagging -->


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/etables.js?v=4"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/ResearchAddToStockList.js?v=4"></script>


    <a id="ServerTagLink" href="http://IBDWEB21">
        <img src="http://www1.ibdcd.com/Images/eTables/px.gif" width="20" height="20" alt="" />
    </a>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https://sb" : "http://b") + ".scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js' %3E%3C/script%3E"));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        COMSCORE.beacon({c1:2,c2:7592510,c3:"",c4:"",c5:"",c6:"",c15:""});
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <img src="http://b.scorecardresearch.com/p?c1=2&c2=7592510&c3=&c4=&c5=&c6=&c15=&cj=1" alt="" />
    </noscript>

</body>
</html>
```

Regards...

Mr.777

Comment: Probably not the real problem but this line should be `while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {`

Comment: And why is it so? I think negative number is EOF, isn't it?

Comment: It may be 0. And 0 is not EOF.

Comment: Well, I have tried that but nothing changed actually :) Waiting for the real answer... THanks though

Comment: What is the output of this line: `System.out.println(response.toString());`?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK [Cache-Control: public, Content-Type: text/html, Expires: Tue, 26 Mar 2013 21:12:31 GMT, Last-Modified: Thu, 21 Feb 2013 21:17:52 GMT, Accept-Ranges: bytes, ETag: "1CE1078E8500000", Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5, CommunityServer: 4.0.30417.1769, Set-Cookie: CSUC=2101; domain=.investors.com; path=/, Set-Cookie: CS-UC2101=lv=Fri, 01 Jan 1999 00:00:00 GMT&mra=Mon, 25 Mar 2013 14:12:31 GMT; expires=Tue, 25-Mar-2014 21:12:31 GMT; path=/, Set-Cookie: CS-LVU-2101=; path=/, X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727, SID: W1, Date: Mon, 25 Mar 2013 21:12:31 GMT, Content-Length: 5995]

Comment: You have some content (Content-Length: 5995) in the response. Is this an error message? What does it say?

Comment: This is just a file. Pasting in the original question. Pasted!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so after a little more research and with the help of @jdb I was able to solve this issue and now I can download the file from the server without any problem after successfully logging in... By the way, thanks @jdb for pointing me in the right direction to make me think what's exactly wrong :)

Pasting code here, if someone else ever wanted to use:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;


public class DownloadAuthenticatedFile{

    public static void main(String... args){

        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://website.com");

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                entity.consumeContent();            
            }
            System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
            List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            }

            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://www.somewebsite.com/MemberSingIn");

            List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "USERNAME"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "PASSWORD"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("remember", "true"));

            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
            entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                entity.consumeContent();
            }

            System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
            cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
            String mySessionId = null;
            if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    if(cookies.get(i).toString().contains("SessionId=")){
                        int index1 = cookies.get(i).toString().indexOf("SessionId");
                        String temp = cookies.get(i).toString().substring(index1);
                        int index2 = temp.toString().indexOf("]");
                        temp = cookies.get(i).toString().substring(index1+10,index1+index2);
                        mySessionId = temp;
                    }
                    System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                }
            } 

            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            httpget = new HttpGet("http://PATHOFWEBSITETOFILE");
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            entity = response.getEntity();
            Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
            for(int i=0;i<headers.length;i++){
                System.out.println("Header: "+headers[i].toString());
            }
            System.out.println(response.toString());

            System.out.println("File get: " + response.getStatusLine());

            InputStream in = entity.getContent();
              File path = new File("/home/mrsevensevenseven");
              path.mkdirs();
              File file = new File(path, "myfile.xls");
              FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              int len1 = 0;
              while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                      fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
              }

              fos.close();

            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```